# Is there a way to reuse @ComponentScan defined in other Configuration class?

Tags: spring-test, spring-context

I'm using Spring Context (v5.2.22 and Java8) and Spring Test in a base framework (consumed by other apps from my team).

To facilitate the setup of tests, I have created a BaseTestContextConfiguration class, containing some common mocked beans, some properties and also some @ComponentScan, aimed to be reused on every test scenarios of the children apps.

```
@ComponentScan("com.ci.common.commands")
public class BaseTestContextConfiguration {
    @Bean("JcommanderBean")
    @Primary
    public Properties getJcommanderProperties() {
        return new Properties();
    }
}
```

But when I try to reuse it the way bellow, creating a new Configuration class (extending from BaseTestContextConfiguration) and passing it to @ContextConfiguration, it is not working as expected. The component scanning defined on parent BaseTestContextConfiguration is not being activated.

```
@ExtendWith({ SpringExtension.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationUnitTest.ContextCommandConfiguration.class})
class ApplicationUnitTest {

    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    public static class ContextCommandConfiguration extends BaseTestContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public MockableAsyncTestTask getMockableTestTask() {

            return Mockito.mock(MockableAsyncTestTask.class);
        }
    }
```

However, if I add the BaseTestContextConfiguration directly to the @ContextConfiguration then the scan works, but this prevent me to override some bean declaration method defined on it.

```
@ExtendWith({ SpringExtension.class })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ContextCommandConfiguration.class, BaseTestContextConfiguration.class })
class ApplicationUnitTest {

    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    public static class ContextCommandConfiguration {
        @Bean("mock")
        @Primary
        public MockableAsyncTestTask getMockableTestTask() {

            MockableAsyncTestTask spied = Mockito.spy(MockableAsyncTestTask.class);
            return spied;
        }
    }
```

I would like to understand the reason of my first approach haven't work, and also if there are more alternatives other than the one I used on my second approach.